# How to create multiple zip folders at once from a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-zipfile

I have a dataframe consisting of users and a list of pdfs related to each of those users. The pdfs have no standard naming convention, there can be any number of pdfs to a list and the number of users is much longer than the example below.

```
import pandas as pd
from zipfile import ZipFile

data = {'name':['aaron', 'ben', 'charlie', 'daniel'],
       'pdfs':[['aaron1.pdf', 'aaron2.pdf', 'aaron3.pdf'],
               ['ben1.pdf', 'ben2.pdf'],
               ['charlie3.pdf', 'charlie5.pdf'],
                ['dan_age.pdf', 'daniel1.pdf']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'pdfs'])
```

Using the ZipFile package I want to run a loop to create a single zip folder for each user that contains within it the relevant pdf documents for only that individual user.

I can successfully create a zip folder for each user in the dataframe using the first two lines of the for loop, however I cannot map the pdf lists to each individual user so that only the pdfs related to each user appear in the correct zip file.

```
users = df['name']
pdfs = df['pdfs']

for user in users:
    zipfiles = ZipFile(user + ".zip", 'w'),
    for zip in zipfiles:
        for lists in pdfs:
            for pdf in lists:
                zip.write(pdf)
```

Using a for loop I want to create seperate zip folders named 'aaron.zip', 'ben.zip', 'charlie.zip', 'daniel.zip' with each folder only containing the pdfs related to that user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making 3 mistakes:

1. You try to iterate over a newly created, empty zip-archive (sidenote: don't use `zip` as variable name, you're overriding a builtin function):

   ```py
       zipfiles = ZipFile(user + ".zip", 'w'),
       for zip in zipfiles:
   ```
2. You try to write every file in `df["pdfs"]` in the user-zip-archive, not only the ones from the user:

   ```py
           for lists in pdfs:
               for pdf in lists:
   ```
3. You don't use the newly created zip-archive to write to:

   ```py
                   zip.write(pdf)
   ```

You could try the following instead:

```py
def zip_user_files(row):
    user, files = row
    with ZipFile(user + ".zip", "w") as archive:
        for file in files:
            archive.write(file)

df[["name", "pdfs"]].apply(zip_user_files, axis=1)
```

I have used `df[["name", "pdfs"]]` instead of `df` just in case the dataframe has actually more columns. If that's not the case just use `df`.

Alternative if you don't want to use `.apply`:

```py
for user, files in zip(df["name"], df["pdfs"]):
    with ZipFile(user + ".zip", "w") as archive:
        for file in files:
            archive.write(file)
```